# getting first images next to id with DOMXpath::query

Tags: php, html, dom, domdocument, domxpath

```
 <span class="byline">
 <ul class="foobar"></ul>
 <img alt="" src="resize_image.php?src=images/newsManagement/87600069ef0dffad5fd02f862ea3787b.jpg&w=675&h=675">
 <p style="text-align: justify;">
 <img alt="" src="resize_image.php?src=images/newsManagement/87600069ef0dffad5fd02f862ea3787b.jpg&w=675&h=675">
 <hr>
```

Hi this is my html.  I can fetch all images using DOMDocument but i want to get first images that comes after `ul.foobar` class. I don't want other images. How can I query for that.

I tried this  for all images.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($url);

//$xpath = new DomXpath($doc);
//$entries = $xpath->query("//div[@id='newsbox']/ul[@class='foobar']");

$elements = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
if (!is_null($elements)) {
  foreach ($elements as $element) {
    echo "<br/>". $element->getAttribute('src'). ": ";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use DOMXPath [query](http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php) with this xpath expression:

```
$image = $xpath->query('//ul[@class="foobar"]/following-sibling::img')->item(0);
```

This will get the following img siblings for `<ul class="foobar">` using [following-sibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/following-sibling) and then get the first item.

The `$image` is of type [DOMElement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php).

In this example I've used [loadHTML](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) to load the html from a string `$source`.
If you want to load your html from a file, you could for example use [loadHTMLFile](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtmlfile.php).

```
$source = <<<SOURCE
<span class="byline">
 <ul class="foobar"></ul>
 <img alt="" src="resize_image.php?src=images/newsManagement/87600069ef0dffad5fd02f862ea3787b.jpg&w=675&h=675">
 <p style="text-align: justify;">
 <img alt="" src="resize_image.php?src=images/newsManagement/87600069ef0dffad5fd02f862ea3787b.jpg&w=675&h=675">
 <hr>
SOURCE;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($source);
$xpath = new DomXpath($dom);
$image = $xpath->query('//ul[@class="foobar"]/following-sibling::img')->item(0);
```

Comment: I want to get first image next to ul tag with class foobar. Image is not inside ul tag.